# How to make a cos function with decreasing wavelength

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

How could I decrease the wavelength, as x increases in a cos function?

Comment: You want $\cos(f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is a [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), i.e. as $x$ increases the rate of change of $f(x)$ increases. For example you could have $\cos\left(x^2\right)$ or $\cos\left(e^x\right)$.

Comment: Also, none of the tags you added (except maybe [geometry]) describe your problem well. Next time, have a look at the tag descriptions before deciding what tags to add.

Comment: @Stacy A differential equation can be set up with some amplitude and wavelength. But you have not specified how the amplitude should vary.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve that, but the simplest is to use
$$\cos(x^k)$$
where the real constant $k \gt 1$ determines how rapidly the wavelength decreases as $x$ increses.